# Problem with cyrillic characters in MacTex and OS X El Captain

Tags: texstudio, mactex, mac, cyrillic

I have a problem with cyrillic fonts (T2A) in OS X El Captain. Every time I try to compile a document that contains cyrillic characters (such as following), I get an error.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Самое обычное предложение на русском языке.
\end{document}
```

The result would be

```
Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
pdfTeX error (font): invalid font identifier. \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

The larm1200.log file starts with the following lines:

```
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_10) (preloaded base=mf 2016.5.6)  7 MAY 2016 02:52
**\mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input larm1200
(/Users/Nikolay/.texlive2015/texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a/larm1200.mf
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/source/lh/base/fikparm.mf
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/source/public/cm/cmbase.mf)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/source/lh/base/lcyrbeg.mf)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/source/lh/base/lkligtbl.mf)
>> 12
>> "input ecrm"
! I can't find file `ecrm'.
```

It looks like there are some access rights problem, as [this post](https://aseev.im/kak-pravilno-ustanovit-latex-na-mac-os-x-el-capitan/) suggests disabling El Captain rootless system integrity protection to solve the problem. 
I found the missing `ecrm1200.tfm` in `/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/ecrm1200.tfm.`

I tried to `chmod 755` the whole fonts folder with no particular results.

I'm using MacTex 2015 and TeXstudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the whole thing had something to do with TeXstudio, as I was able to compile my file with TeXshop. Moreover, now TeXstudio compiles this file without any problems.

In case someone has this particular problem:

- make sure you have `collection-fontsrecommended` and `collection-fontsextra` packages installed
- try compiling your file with TeXshop